# Mongodb group by key

Tags: mongodb

I have the following recordset as result of a find:

```
[{ 'programming': 7 },
{ 'programming': 9 },
{ 'programming': 6 },
{ 'programming': 10 },
{ 'music': 1 },
{ 'music': 2 },
{ 'music': 3 },
{ 'music': 4 }]
```

I want to group them by the key and sum the value, to have:

```
[{'programming': 32},
 {'music': 10}]
```

sort them by the value (in this case, first programming and then music) and limit by 3 (if there is `programming 32`, `music 10`, `shopping 3` and `lifestyle 1`, only return `programming`, `shopping` and `lifestyle`.

How to aggregate such data? Should I use mapreduce, aggregate or simply group? If so, how to tell group to group by the dictionary key?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Hope this will help.

tested on : v3.6.5

```
db.cname.aggregate([
{
    $project:
    {
        _id: 0
    }
},
{
    $project:
    {
        "o":
        {
            $objectToArray: "$$ROOT"
        }
    }
},
{
    $unwind: "$o"
},
{
    $group:
    {
        _id: "$o.k",
        value:
        {
            $sum: "$o.v"
        }
    }
}])
```

OUTPUT

```
{ "_id" : "music", "value" : 10 }

{ "_id" : "programming", "value" : 32 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Doing that by keys would kill your query maintainability.

My best tip is: create another key, say `skill` (which will be the document grouping key) and a key called `value`.
Then you would get a query somewhat like this:

```
db.skills.aggregate([{
  $group: {
    _id: "$skill",
    value: { $sum: "$value" }
  }
}])
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I'd recommend going @gustavohenke's route with not grouping by keys, you *can* do it using mapreduce (I can't think of a way of doing it with aggregations which would be the more straight forward route)

```js
> var mapFunction = function() {
     for(var key in this) { 
        if(key!='_id') emit(key, this[key]); 
     } 
  };

> var reduceFunction = function(key, values) { return Array.sum(values); }

> db.data.mapReduce(mapFunction, reduceFunction, { out: 'bop' })
{
    "result" : "bop",
    "timeMillis" : 47,
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 8,
        "emit" : 8,
        "reduce" : 2,
        "output" : 2
    },
    "ok" : 1,
}
> db.bop.find().sort({value: -1}).limit(3)
{ "_id" : "programming", "value" : 32 }
{ "_id" : "music", "value" : 10 }
>
```